# How do i use SQL codeing Within my class?

Tags: sql, delphi, class, delphi-7

I have created a class that has to use SQL-code to do a validation check from my database but when i try to run my program it does not use the ADOquery from my form. I have tried to fix it by adding my main unit to my class's unit but it then gives a circulation error. I have also tried to add Form1 into the uses(that is the name of my form and i only have one form) but then it does not understand Form1. If any one can help, it would be very appreciated.

orait this is in my class:

```
procedure TCheckA.CheckIfAdmin;
var iRecordA : Integer;
begin
    qryInfo.Active := False;
    qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
    qryInfo.SQL.Add(' Select [Lid Naam], [Lid Wagwoord], Adminustrateur ');
    qryInfo.SQL.Add(' From [CATSA Lede] ');
    qryInfo.SQL.Add(' Where [Lid Naam] = "'+fgebruikernaam+'"and [Lid Wagwoord] = "'+fpassword+'" and Adminustrateur = True ');
    qryInfo.Active := True;
    iRecordA := qryinfo.recordcount;


 if iRecordA = 1
  then begin
   fAdminAnswer := True;
   end
  else begin
   fAdminAnswer := False;
  end;
end;
```

Then it throughs this error: `[Error] IntekenCheck.pas(29): Undeclared identifier: 'qryInfo'`

Then if i try to put my main unit in my class's unit Like:

```
unit IntekenCheck;

interface
 uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, Buttons, jpeg, ExtCtrls, XPMan, Grids,
  DBGrids, DB, ADODB, Math, AdminCheck, Chairmin_u{main unit};
```

Then the error is: `[Fatal Error] IntekenCheck.pas(7): Circular unit reference to 'IntekenCheck'`

Comment: Can you show the code that's failing and provide specific error messages that you receive?

Comment: Hay guys when i posted this question I was still programming stupid and did not think to build my queries in my classes and then just return it to my main program. Thank you all for help i do appreciate it and i will keep these tips in mind. BTW i now code in C# rather then delphi but principles stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the query into your class, and use it there:

```
procedure TCheckA.CheckIfAdmin(const Query: TAdoQuery);
begin
  AQuery.Active := False;
  AQuery.SQL.Clear;
  AQuery.SQL.Add(' Select [Lid Naam], [Lid Wagwoord], Adminustrateur ');
  AQuery.SQL.Add(' From [CATSA Lede] ');
  AQuery.SQL.Add(' Where [Lid Naam] = "' + fgebruikernaam +
                 '"and [Lid Wagwoord] = "'+ fpassword + 
                 '" and Adminustrateur = True ');
  AQuery.Active := True;
  fAdminAnswer := (AQuery.RecordCount = 1);
end;
```

(You should also change to use parameterized queries instead rather than contatenation with `+`. It's much more secure. There are many other questions  here relating to parameterized queries and Delphi; a quick search on `[delphi] parameter query` should find them for you.)